# Create new file type association

Tags: gnome, mime-types

Let's assume I have a program X that uses files with the extension .xez. How can I make X the default application for all files with the extension .xez?

My first idea was `xdg-mime default X.desktop application/.xez`. Yet this does not work.

Files with the extension .xez are still associated with Gnome Archive Manager since files with .xez represent a sort of .zip archive.

Comment: I suppose it works based on MIME types, that is, the *actual* file type, not extensions... are you sure ".xez" files aren't actually a ZIP archive? What's the output of "file whatever.xez"?

Comment: I guess you're right: `[orschiro@thinkpad ~]$ file testfile.pez 
testfile.pez: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract`. Is there any way to link .pez to X whilst still preserving .zip to be opened with File Roller?